# feh image viewer: reloading displayed image from external command

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, reload, image-viewer

Someone know a way to send on Linux an "instruction" (like a system command) to an already open feh instance to reload the same image already loaded or maybe another one?
I have seen feh doing relatively complex task via shell scripts, but I am struggling to obtain just this feature.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `xdotool search ...` to get the *WindowId* of `feh`, then send `r` (for `refresh`) using `xdotool key --windowid XYZ r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `-R` flag to get it to reload every few seconds.

It's also possible that sending `SIGUSR1` (if you know the PID, that's as easy as `kill SIGUSR1 $pid`) would be sufficient to get it to reload; that usually forces it to go to the next photo, but if there is no next photo it might force a reload of the current one.

Comment: Works well - nice one!

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated.

Comment: Your PID method doesn't seem to work anymore, could this be correct?